# RPI HDD Spins down and detaches

Tags: raspbian, hard-drive

I have plugged an external HDD drive to my RPI. The hdd has it's own power supply but after several hours I discovered that RPI can't access the drive and worse... filesystem is broken. This repeated two times and I unplugged HDD from RPI and used USB flash instead. But recently I realized that HDD spins down and on windows it needs several seconds to access filesystem while HDD spins up.
Maybe Raspbian is not so smart? How to fix it? Any advice?

Comment: *Maybe Raspbian is not so smart?* -- it's not that dumb no.  Like, this is isn't supposed to happen.  I have an external HDD attached on a powered hub and have never had any problems, so there's something specific that's going wrong in your case.  You don't describe what you mean by "filesystem is broken" or how you came to that conclusion, which might help.

Comment: @goldilocks Thanks for your reply. AFAIK the spin-down feature depends on HDD itself and SATA-USB bridge. In your case HDD could never spin-down. When I wrote 'filesystem was broken' I meant that I had to fix it (NTFS) with CHKDSK on Windows PC in order to get the data back and I could not get my data back in case of Ext4